# remove navigation controller inserted with storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I insert a navigation controller in my project at the beginning of the work using `editor->embed in->Navigation Controller`.
Now I realize that is better to insert a tab bar instead of the navigation controller, but I'm unable to remove it! The unembed item in the editor menu is always grey, each item i select...
How can I do this job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just select the navController in storyboard and delete it. Then you need to add a tab bar controller to it(you can do this same way as nav controller:Editor -> Embed In -> Tab Bar Controller) and wire it up with the view controllers as you require it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ajeet, Thank you, I found some hours later the same solution you give me.
so your answer was right ;) thank you

Comment: But what if you don't want to use a tab controller? I also need to remove the navigation controller, as I just want to show a single view. Removing the navigation controller causes a huge list of errors.

Comment: @PietBinnenbocht If you have single view to show and you don't require navigationController or tabController then you don't have to do anything. Just use the view storyboard creates for you by default. And you if plan of deleting everything on storyboard and start again fresh -> Drag the view controller to the storyboard and mark it as the initial view. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

"unembed" function is for unembedding the "stack" in stackView and not for "navigation controller" nor "tab bar controller". That's why the unembed item in the editor menu is always grey.